# I cannot click the buttons used for animations in LaTeX

Tags: ubuntu, animations, animate

[image]

I am new to LaTeX, feel free to treat me as a newbie.
Here, you can see this image there are some controls to play the gif.
They are not working in my Linux machine, ubuntu. I installed all packages, I divided the gif into frames but still, I face the same. By the way, I am using xelatex and evince.
Can you please suggest me a  solution.
There's no error or something, pdf is generated but the animations are not working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In your case of course the document could be fine and it is an issue with evince, but even then someone could easily reproduce it.

Comment: Please see the `animate` package manual, it lists the requirements. Anumations presumably requires javascript support in the PDF viewer, there aren't many of those and Evince is not one of them.

Comment: On Linux, recent versions of **KDE Okular** support JavaScript-based animations.